# How can I set my batch script to check all sub-folders of a specified location?

Tags: batch-file

As of right now, this script functions as I would like, however it will only search within FolderA.

Example; FolderA\product\productype\version\FolderB

I would like to expand on the script to have it search all .xml files in all locations from FolderA to FolderB and output the "package" result into an output.txt file.

```
@echo OFF

del output.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<package>" *.xml' "FolderA\*"') do call     :job "%%i"

goto :eof

:job

set line=%1

set line=%line:/=%
set line=%line:<=+%
set line=%line:>=+%
set line=%line:*+string+=%
set line=%line:+=&rem.%
echo.%line%>>output.txt



:eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `/s` switch to the `findstr`.

see

```
findstr /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.